# Directional derivative

Tags: math

I know that D ⃗ v f = ∇ f ⋅ ⃗ v Dv→f=∇f⋅v→ is the directional derivative. My question is why must the vector ⃗ v v→ be a unit vector? I am sure there is an obvious answer, but my book doesn't really explain it.

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/directional-derivative.906813/

Comment: This is a math question without any relation to signal processing...